# Windows 8 printer settings missing

Tags: windows-8, printing

I'm using an Epson Stylus SX600FW printer via WLAN on Windows 8.1.
On Windows XP I used to have a lot of options in the printer settings, which looked like this:
[image: extensive printer settings]

For example I could choose to print multiple pages of a PDF on a single page (under Page Layout) etc.
Now, under Windows 8 the settings window looks like this even though I have installed the newest driver from Epson(this is not the generic Windows Printer Driver) 
[image: limited printer settings]

How can I bring back the extensive printing preferences?

Comment: Did you install the Driver with the USB cable plugged in? Without this it unlikely will work.

Comment: The driver installation process for this is very cranky, capricious, sou you need to follow instructions exactly step by step.

Comment: Did you install this driver (as per the Windows Compatibility site): http://www.epson.co.uk/gb/en/viewcon/corporatesite/products/mainunits/support/2933/25

Comment: Thank you for the hint @RuslanGerasimov :) A reinstallation did it, which I should have known...

Comment: Yes, with Epson it is like that...glad to know it is all right now.

Answer (score 1):

> I have installed the newest driver from Epson

The latest Windows 8 Epson driver for your printer is
[v6.67 from 24-Oct-2012](http://www.epson.co.uk/gb/en/viewcon/corporatesite/products/mainunits/support/2933/25).

It seems that this driver package was not the one that was installed on your computer,
because you did a network installation that installed the Windows driver that was
exposed by the printer's firmware and was built
into the firmware when the printer was fabricated (probably in 2011),
a driver which was incompatible with Windows 8.

The above driver from 2012 is compatible with Windows 8 and Printer Settings.

Comment: Thank you for this elaborate answer which would have convinced me if I couldn't get it to work the second time around.

Comment: This answer was based on your text: "I have installed the newest driver from Epson". If it would have been "from WLAN", the usual remedy is always to try a local installation first, because the printer's firmware does not usually publish the latest driver. I have modified my answer.

Answer (score 0):

It works now. The problem was that the installation failed because I wanted it to install via WLAN the first time around. Strangely, it seems as it was only partly installed. A reinstallation using a USB connection resolved the problem. I now have the extensive set of printing options again.